# Criteria Query saying wrong type (Postgres operator does not exist)

Tags: postgresql, jpa, criteria-api

I have this query in which I only want Employees that do not have an `empId`, `usrId`, and `empIdentifier` in the `Action` table of my DB (the three form a foreign key in the Action table).

```
    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Emp> q = cb.createQuery(Emp.class);
    Root<Emp> c = q.from(Emp.class);

    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

    Subquery<Action> sq = q.subquery(Action.class);
    Root<Action> ac = sq.from(Action.class);

    sq.select(ac);
    sq.where(cb.equal(ac.get("actionCd"), "CLOSE"));

    predicates.add(c.get("empId").in(sq).not());
    predicates.add(c.get("usrId").in(sq).not());
    predicates.add(c.get("empIdentifier").in(sq).not());

    ....

    q.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[]{}));
```

When I execute this query I get the following error:

```
 org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: text = numeric
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

`empId` and `usrId` are both numeric fields in my DB, however `empIdentifier` is text. If I have just `empId` and `userId` or just `empIdentifier` predicates the query works fine, however I need all three together. It seems I can only query numeric values OR text values and not the two together.

How can I get around this? Is this a postgres or JPA issue? I have double and triple checked my DB and classes and they all have the appropriate types. For some reason it thinks `empIdentifier` is a numeric value or is comparing it against a numeric value instead of text like it truly is.

Edit:

SQL query from log:

```
from emps."emp" emp0_ where 

(emp0_."empid" not in  (select action1_."actionid" from emps."action" action1_ 
where action1_."actioncd"=?))

 and 

(emp0_."usrid" not in  (select action2_."actionid" from emps."action" action2_ 
where action2_."actioncd"=?)) 

and 

(emp0_."empidentifier" not in  (select action3_."actionid" from emps."action" 
action3_ where action3_."actioncd"=?))
```

Comment: care to tell us what SQL was actually executed? because all JPA providers convert Criteria into SQL, and show the SQL in their log.

Comment: @NeilStockton Please see my edit. This is as detailed as I could get out of hibernate. Thanks!

Comment: look for columns that are of type "text" that appear in that (partial) SQL. Maybe a parameter is passed in as numeric and compared to a "text" column? since you don't post the application of parameters no way anyone can guess further. The SQL is missing off the "SELECT ..." part btw

Comment: @NeilStockton Yeah its some type mismatch but I cant seem to find anything mismatches myself. I do have a select part but its very long and I think not important for my problem.